Fluter OneSignal.shared.postNotification method for version 5
Does anyone know how to post for a notification in onesignal_flutter version 5?
in onesignal_flutter 3.5.1
I do use
var notification = OSCreateNotification(
        playerIds: listOneSignalUserId,
        androidSmallIcon: 'ic_stat_one_signal_default',
        androidLargeIcon: 'ic_stat_one_signal_default',
        content: message,
        androidSound: sound,
        heading: title,
        languageCode: 'en',
        iosAttachments: {
          "id1": imgUrlString
        },
        //url: url,
        //bigPicture: imgUrlString,
        buttons: [
          OSActionButton(text: "OK", id: "id1"),
        ]);

    var response = await OneSignal.shared.postNotification(notification);

But seems that this wont work at version 5
is there any solution how to post a notification in version 5 ?
Thanks

Manage to send / create notification by using http post
const apiUrl = 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications';

final Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic $oneSignalApiKey',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
};

final Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = {
  "app_id": oneSignalAppId,
  "include_player_ids": listOneSignalUserId,
  "headings": {
    'en': title,
  },
  "contents": {
    "en": message,
  },
  "sdk_type": "flutter",
  "large_icon": imgUrlString,
};

try {
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(apiUrl),
    headers: headers,
    body: jsonEncode(requestBody),
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Notification sent Successfully");
  } else {
    print(
        "Failed to send Notification, Status code: ${response.statusCode}");
  }
} on Exception catch (e) {
  print("Error with sending push notification - $e");
}

